# Is it possible to chain setTimeout functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Is it possible to chain `setTimout` functions to ensure they run after one another?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Three separate approaches listed here:

1. Manually nest `setTimeout()` callbacks.
2. Use a chainable timer object.
3. Wrap `setTimeout()` in a promise and chain promises.

**Manually Nest setTimeout callbacks**

Of course.  When the first one fires, just set the next one.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // do something
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do second thing
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

**Chainable Timer Object**

You can also make yourself a little utility object that will let you literally chain things which would let you chain calls like this:

```
delay(fn1, 400).delay(fn2, 500).delay(fn3, 800);
```

```js
function delay(fn, t) {
    // private instance variables
    var queue = [], self, timer;
    
    function schedule(fn, t) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            timer = null;
            fn();
            if (queue.length) {
                var item = queue.shift();
                schedule(item.fn, item.t);
            }
        }, t);            
    }
    self = {
        delay: function(fn, t) {
            // if already queuing things or running a timer, 
            //   then just add to the queue
           if (queue.length || timer) {
                queue.push({fn: fn, t: t});
            } else {
                // no queue or timer yet, so schedule the timer
                schedule(fn, t);
            }
            return self;
        },
        cancel: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            queue = [];
            return self;
        }
    };
    return self.delay(fn, t);
}

function log(args) {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "object") {
            str += JSON.stringify(arguments[i]);
        } else {
            str += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var target = log.id ? document.getElementById(log.id) : document.body;
    target.appendChild(div);
}


function log1() {
   log("Message 1");
}
function log2() {
   log("Message 2");
}
function log3() {
   log("Message 3");
}

var d = delay(log1, 500)
    .delay(log2, 700)
    .delay(log3, 600)
```

**Wrap setTimeout in a Promise and Chain Promises**

Or, since it's now the age of promises in ES6+, here's similar code using promises where we let the promise infrastructure do the queuing and sequencing for us.  You can end up with a usage like this:

```
Promise.delay(fn1, 500).delay(fn2, 700).delay(fn3, 600);
```

Here's the code behind that:

```js
// utility function for returning a promise that resolves after a delay
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

Promise.delay = function (fn, t) {
    // fn is an optional argument
    if (!t) {
        t = fn;
        fn = function () {};
    }
    return delay(t).then(fn);
}

Promise.prototype.delay = function (fn, t) {
    // return chained promise
    return this.then(function () {
        return Promise.delay(fn, t);
    });

}

function log(args) {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "object") {
            str += JSON.stringify(arguments[i]);
        } else {
            str += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var target = log.id ? document.getElementById(log.id) : document.body;
    target.appendChild(div);
}

function log1() {
    log("Message 1");
}

function log2() {
    log("Message 2");
}

function log3() {
    log("Message 3");
}

Promise.delay(log1, 500).delay(log2, 700).delay(log3, 600);
```

The functions you supply to this version can either by synchonrous or asynchronous (returning a promise).

Comment: I apologise for my dumb questions, but are there any internet browsers which process javascript functions concurrently, (including mobile), and if so does this ensure that they don't run concurrently?

Comment: All browser javascript is single threaded.  One thread of execution runs at a time so sequential statements are always run one after the other.  Two pieces of javascript NEVER run concurrently.

Comment: Added a chainable timer object with queuing and a cancel method.

Comment: Can the fn argument of delay be a function that takes an argument like function logMessage(message) { log(message); }? And if so, how could I pass in the message argument?

Comment: @GeeBrownit - You can't pass `logMessage(message)` directly.  You can make a wrapper function that calls `log(message)` itself.  Or you can use `.bind()` to bind an argument to the callback you pass.  I'd suggest you ask your own question about how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, bind is sweet and works. For anyone whose interested here https://jsfiddle.net/efbbrown/ypa25gsc/1/ is how you can bind inputs to the fn argument.

Comment: Added a version using promises to handle the async sequencing for us.

Comment: Why do you have `Promise.delay` and `Promise.prototype.delay`? Can you combine the 2?

Comment: @guest - There are situations where you want a static function like `Promise.delay()` that returns a new promise and there are reasons why you want to insert a `.delay()` into an existing promise chain.  These are separate use cases that require a slightly different wrapper around the core functionality.  You can see from the code that `Promise.prototype.delay()` uses `Promise.delay()` in its implementation, but works on an existing promise chain.

Comment: Added better summary of the three options listed here.

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by the Promise-based solution in [jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921279/6904888), I demonstrated a shorter version:

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => delay(400))
  .then(() => log1())
  .then(() => delay(500))
  .then(() => log2())
  .then(() => delay(800))
  .then(() => log3());

function delay(duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

function log1() {
  console.log("Message 1");
}

function log2() {
  console.log("Message 2");
}

function log3() {
  console.log("Message 3");
}
```

Comment: This works better for me, the code is as concise as it gets.

Answer (score 6):

With ES6, this is pretty simple using `async`/`await`. This is also very easy to read and a little upgrade to the promises answer.

```js
// Expect to be async
    async function timePush(...arr){
        function delay(t){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    resolve();
                },t)
            })
        }
        // for the length of this array run a delay
        // then log, you could always use a callback here
        for(let i of arr){
            //pass the items delay to delay function
            await delay(i.time);
            console.log(i.text)
        }
    }
    
    
    timePush(
        {time:1000,text:'hey'},
        {time:5000,text:'you'},
        {time:1000,text:'guys'}
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue. My solution was to call self by `setTimeout`, it works.

```js
let a = [[20,1000],[25,5000],[30,2000],[35,4000]];

function test(){
  let b = a.shift();
  console.log(b[0]);
  if(a.length == 0) return;
  setTimeout(test,b[1]);
}
```

the second element in array a is time to be delayed

Answer (score 1):

Using `async / await` with [@Penny Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62034951/3206247) example:

```js
(async() => {
  await delay(400)
  log1()
  await delay(500)
  log2()
  await delay(800)
  log3()
})()

async function delay(duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

function log1() {
  console.log("Message 1");
}

function log2() {
  console.log("Message 2");
}

function log3() {
  console.log("Message 3");
}
```

Comment: I like this style of `delay` call, but `async` like a virus: one async, all (call stack functions) need be async