# slider , line is running before setTimeout , and after mouse over to execute script once , until all slides are completed

Tags: jquery, settimeout, onmouseover

Hi i have this html

```
<div class="slideListHolder clearfix">
                        <div class="cntBoxes">
                            <div class="mainBox" id="list-1">
                                <img src="img/m1.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt="" />
                                <a class="link" target="_blank" href="http://test.euwebstudio.jp/ntt/careerup/premium/index2.html">詳細はこちら</a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-1">
                                <img src="img/img1.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-2">
                                <img src="img/img6.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-3">
                                <img src="img/img11.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>

                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-4">
                                <img src="img/img16.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-5">
                                <img src="img/img21.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cntBoxes">

                            <div class="mainBox" id="list-2">
                                <img src="img/m2.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-1">
                                <img src="img/img2.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-2">
                                <img src="img/img7.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="box id-3">
                                <img src="img/img12.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-4">
                                <img src="img/img17.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box id-5">
                                <img src="img/img22.jpg"width="200" height="400" alt=""/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this js

```
var cntBoxes='.slideListHolder .cntBoxes';
var time = 300;

$(cntBoxes).mouseover(function() {
    if(!$(this).parent('div').hasClass('dc') && !$(this).parent('div').hasClass('over')){
    $(cntBoxes).parent('div').addClass('over');

        var elem = $(this);
        pieces=elem.children('.mainBox').attr('id').split('list-');

        if (typeof pieces[1] !== "undefined") {
                $(cntBoxes).children('.mainBox').each(function(){
                    var $this=$(this)
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        $this.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                            var showId='.id-'+pieces[1];
                            $this.parent('div').children(showId).fadeIn('fast');
                        });
                    },time)
                    time += 300;
                });
                $(cntBoxes).parent('div').addClass('dc');
                $(cntBoxes).parent('div').removeClass('over');
        }

    }




})

$(cntBoxes).click(function() {
    if($(this).parent('div').hasClass('dc')){

        $(cntBoxes).children('.box:visible').each(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $(this).parent('div').children('.mainBox').fadeIn('slow');
            });

        });
        $(cntBoxes).parent('div').removeClass('dc');
    }
});
```

how to do , this line `$(cntBoxes).parent('div').removeClass('over');`,  after `setTimeout( function(){`  , and how is possible mouse over until all slides are finished , this script is executing multiple times . Thank You A LOT , Sorry if Explanation is not so clear

Comment: Miru, nobody's gonna help you((

Answer (score 0):

You would have already solved this question. doesn't matter for me, maybe one another see this and use. First, in java script, timer functions are asynchronous like ajax functions. They are started at different treads It means your code will be continuing right after your setTimeout  function without waiting it to be ended/returned.

There are some ways to do it with using queues, TimeoutChain ...

[you should look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921275/is-it-possible-to-chain-settimeout-functions-in-javascript)
I know its not a good answer but i think it could give good clues about the problem.