# setTimeout in do while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout

I try to output an alert box with the message "hello" every 2 seconds, but only 5 times. So I wrote this code:

```
var counter = 1;

do {
    setTimeout
    (
        function()
        {
             alert("hello");
             counter++;
        },
        2000
    );
} while( counter <= 5 );
```

But my page keeps crashing everytime? Why?
Whats the best way to add a delay of 2000ms between the alerts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to chain setTimeout functions in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921275/is-it-possible-to-chain-settimeout-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But my page crashes everytime? Why?

Because the counter is only incremented inside the callback - the loop probably tries to run thousands (if not tens of thousands) of times in that time and quickly runs the browser out of memory. More accurately, as is pointed out in comments, the loop never gives up control to the `setTimeout` call - so that is never going to get run (Dont worry too much about the distinction here - just accept that your counter is not being incremented)

> Whats the best way to add a delay of 2000ms between the alerts

Kick off the next one only as the previous one finishes.

```
function showHello(i){
  if(i<5){
    setTimeout
    (
        function()
        {
             alert("hello");
             showHello(i+1)
        },
        2000
    );
  }
}

showHello(0);
```

Related: [Is it possible to chain setTimeout functions in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921275/is-it-possible-to-chain-settimeout-functions-in-javascript) and [how to make a setInterval stop after some time or after a number of actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136261/how-to-make-a-setinterval-stop-after-some-time-or-after-a-number-of-actions)

Comment: "in that time" — It never even gets to that point. The JS event loop is too busy running the `while` to see if any timers have run out, so it will never hit the timed out function.

Comment: The timeout callback is never executed actually, because the loop never gives up control. You could set the delay to 0 and it would still crash.

Comment: You're both absolutely accurate, of course. As the OP is struggling with this concept I think we can assume thats going to just confuse them. I have updated the answer nonetheless

Comment: Well, answers shouldn't be correct, shouldn't they? Also, just in general, I doubt that browsers crash when a loop runs for 2 seconds.

Comment: @Felix you're too quick on the draw. I was updating

Comment: So the setTimeout function does not pause the execution of the while loop?

Comment: @EdwardBlack- absolutely not.

Comment: Sorry, i better ask twice than understand it incorrectly. But by saying "absolutely not" do you mean that my statement was correct and the setTimeout function does not pause the execution of the while loop?

Comment: @EdwardBlack I meant it does not pause the loop.

Comment: oh ok, now i begin to understand the concept. Thanks.

Comment: @EdwardBlack: This might help learning about JavaScript's execution model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop .

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval instead:

```
var counter = 0; // setting the counter
var interval = setInterval(function(){ //setInterval does repeatedly what setTimeout only
                                       //does once
    counter++;
    if(counter === 5){
        clearInterval(interval); //if the counter reaches 5 (the times you asked
                                 //for repeating the alert box) you clear the interval,
                                 //stopping the loop
    }
    alert("hello");
}, 2000);
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwosm34x/

Comment: That only answers part of the question and provides no explanation of the solution.

Comment: @FelixKling made some comments on the code, hope it's better explained now (I'm new to answering on stackoverflow, still have to perfect answering practices)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` instead.

And `clearInterval()` when the counter is greater than 5.

```js
var counter = 1;

var timer = setInterval(function () {
  alert("hello "+counter);
  counter++;
  if (counter > 5) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: "Try this" with no explanation of the code, or what was wrong helps nobody