# why setState hook in the map set last object only?

Tags: hook, setstate, react-admin

I have 2 components in react-admin the child one set the state of the parent one.

the child component has useEffect to trigger the following method in parent component

```html
 const [approved, setAproved] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(approved))
 }, [approved]) 

    const setapprovedamount = (id, approvedAmount) => {
              
          if(approved.length!==0)
          {
          // if the child run 3 times 
          
          // this line runs 3 times 
            console.log("set Aproved with" +id+ " and amount : "+approvedAmount)
            
            
          // but this line update only the last object 
            setAproved(
              approved.map(item => 
              (item.id == id)
              ? {...item, totalApproved : approvedAmount}
              : item
              )
            )
          }
          else
          {
          setAproved(approved =>[...approved, {
            id: id,
            totalApproved: approvedAmount
          }] ) 
          }
    }

  useEffect(() => {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(approved))
  }, [approved])
```

```html
So **for example** if I have 3 times load, the Console is: 

    file.js:168 set Aproved with44 and amount : 799.71
    file.js:168 set Aproved with45 and amount : 845.98
    file.js:168 set Aproved with46 and amount : 890.83

    file.js:96 
    [{"id":44,"totalApproved":null},{"id":45,"totalApproved":null},{"id":46,"totalApproved":890.83}]
```

so the method runs 3 times as it is triggered but, it is setting only the last value rendered in the state array in the parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) works.

If you wanted to fire multiple and chained state updates through`setState`, you need to let the component complete its cycle at each state update - first things first.

Therefore, the basic solution is to imply the use of [chained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921275/is-it-possible-to-chain-settimeout-functions-in-javascript) `setTimeout` calls to delegate each state update, letting each function call complete a component, full life cycle.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setState(firstState)
    setTimeout(function() {
        setState(secondState)
    });
});
```